# How to make OpenAPI/Swagger ignore some properties of models?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

This is my path:

```
/options/register:
        post:
          summary: Create a new option.
          tags:
            - Option
          requestBody:
            required: true
            content:
              application/json:
                schema:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Option'
```

and my model is:

```
Option:
  type: object
  properties: 
    id: 
      type: integer
    name:
      type: string
    description:
    optionPhotoUrl:
       type: string
```

The problem is i use the same model for create and update, where the ID is not required to create and some fields are not updateable, how can i ignore certain properties on certain calls?

Answer (score 2):

I think that readOnly/ writeOnly keyword are for you you

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#readonly-writeonly